# JAX-B mapping String to JAXBElement<String>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm trying to do something that should be relatively simple, add a sub class to my root element that contains only Strings. On the client side however this object has JAXBElement mapped instead of Strings. See below:

```
public class Foo {
    protected Bar barObject;
}

public class Bar {
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected String barName;
}
```

The generated Bar bean looks like this.

```
public class Bar {
    @XmlElementRef(name = "barName", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> barString;
}
```

I'm sure this is kicking a dead horse, but I don't see a clear explanation of this behavior anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JAXB implementation will generate a property of type `JAXBElement` if the corresponding element is `nillalbe="true"` and `minOccurs-"0"`.  This is so that it can round trip both states.

```
<element name="barName" type="string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

You can make the element `minOccurs="1"` by specifying the `required` flag on `@XmlElement`.

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true, required=true)
protected String barName;
```